# Add DateField in editable grid on vaadin framework

Tags: java, vaadin

I`m new to Vaadin. In my project I have a grid that was set editable, when I double click on grid, editing is enabled.

In my grid when editing was enabled, in the grid the `datefield` set as an editable field.

I was using `grid.setEditedField(editableField)` but it was throwing an error.

```
gridAssetDetail.getColumn("assignDate").setEditorField(getDateField());
private Field<?> getDateField() { 
  DateField editDate = new DateField();
  editDate.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  return editDate;
}
```

That way, the String format does not change to datefield.

Error:

```
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: 
Could not convert '07/04/1914' to java.util.Date
```

Comment: Please post also the error

Comment: gridAssetDetail.getColumn("assignDate").setEditorField(getDateField());private Field<?> getDateField() {
  DateField  editDate = new DateField();
  editDate.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  return editDate;
 }

Comment: That's not an error. Add to your question the error that throw when you use `grid.setEditedField(editableField)`

Comment: Caused by: com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Could not convert '07/04/1914' to java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your error is due to the conversion from `String` to `Date`.

For converting a `String` to a `Date` you have to use a `DateFormat`

```
String string = "07/04/1914";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Or in short:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("07/04/1914");
```

Source: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)